# Apache Karaf stop order problems

Tags: sequence, karaf

we have a problem with the stopping sequece of Karaf ... is there any sequence? :)
Like reverse order for my bundles start-level ... How can I control the start or the stop sequence of Karaf ... not programmatically, but over the config.

My proposals:
1. In the deploy/features.xml??? Maybe start-level definition?
2. Or some depends declarations in the blueprint.xml??
3. Or in the pom.xml over the configuration of the maven-bundle-plugin??

I think the start order is automatically resolved by karaf in the correct way, but how is stop sequece defined???

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shutdown happens in the reverse order to startup.

Informally:

All of the bundles at a particular start level will have `BundleActivator.stop(BundleContext)` called before bundles with a lower start level will be stopped.

http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#stop()

In particular, all of the `stop` invocations will have returned before Bundles with lower start levels are stopped.